# Generating report using IF THEN SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having issues getting a SQL statement to work how I need it to.  To be honest, I'm pretty green when it comes to SQL so the tries I've attempted have come from copy/paste code that I've tried to edit to make work and it's not running.  So what I need is a query to be used for a report in ACCESS.
Here is what data look like:

---

```
ID   TechID   OccurrenceDate                     OccurrenceName          OccurrenceAmt
 247      9991     Friday, February 15, 2013          Coaching                4.50        
242   9991     Friday, February 08, 2013          Con't Occurrence        0.00      
241   9991     Thursday, February 07, 2013        Unscheduled Absense     1.00      
240   9991     Wednesday, February 06, 2013       Shift Int less 2 hrs    0.50
243   9991     Monday, February 04, 2013          Unscheduled Absense     1.00
246   9991     Monday, January 21, 2013           Unscheduled Absense     1.00
245   9991     Wednesday, January 16, 2013        Con't Occurrence        0.00
244   9991     Tuesday, January 15, 2013          Unscheduled Absense     1.00
 239      9999     Friday, February 08, 2013          Unscheduled Absense    1.00
 237      9999     Wednesday, February 06, 2013       Unscheduled Absense    1.00   
 238      9999     Saturday, February 02, 2013        Coaching               7.00
236   9999     Tuesday, September 11, 2012        Other                   6.00
235   9999     Tuesday, September 11, 2012        Other                   0.00
228   9999     Thursday, August 23, 2012          Unscheduled Absense     1.00
227   9999     Friday, August 10, 2012            Unscheduled Absense     1.00
226   9999     Wednesday, August 08, 2012         Con't Occurrence        0.00
223   9999     Wednesday, February 29, 2012       Unscheduled Absense     1.00
 249      9998     Saturday, February 02, 2013        Unscheduled Absense    1.00
 251      9998     Monday, January 21, 2013           Unscheduled Absense    1.00
```

So basically if there is an "OccurrenceName" of either "Coaching" or "Other" within the last 6 months that amount plus any other occurrences within the previous 6 months should be their Tech Total.  If there is are no "Coaching" or "Other" occurrences within the last 6 months then I need to sum the OccurrenceAmount for just the rolling previous 6 months.

Hopefully my very well explained scenario makes sense.

**EDIT #1:**
Okay, my expected output for this data should be:

---

```
TechID     Total
 9991       4.5
 9999       9.0
 9998       2.0
```

So as you can see, for TechID 9991 calculates 4.5 because there was a "Coaching" occurrence and nothing since in the previous 6 months.  9999 would have 9 because there was a Coaching for 7 and two more since then within the previous 6 months bringing that total to 9.  9998 has 2 because that tech has no coaching or anything within the last 6 months so the total is 2.

**EDIT #2:**
So the only lines that should be counted are the lines that are indented.  For 9999, there was a coaching for 7 and 2 more regular occurrences bringing his total to 9.  Is that more clear?

**EDIT #3:** 
Okay, got a little further down the road.
@lance - through trial and error I am getting closer... have this for now, but can't get it working:

`SELECT tblEmployeeData.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.FName, Sum(tblOccurrence.OccurrenceAmt), Last(tblOccurrence.CoachingDate) AS LastOfCoachingDate, tblEmployeeData.SupLName
FROM tblEmployeeData RIGHT JOIN tblOccurrence ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = tblOccurrence.TechID
GROUP BY tblEmployeeData.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.FName, tblEmployeeData.SupLName
HAVING (((tblOccurrence.OccurrenceAmt))=IIf([tblOccurrence].[CoachingDate]="",[tblOccurrence].[OccurrenceDate] Between Date() And DateAdd('m',-6,Date()),IIf([tblOccurrence].[CoachingDate]<=DateAdd('m',-6,Date()),[tblOccurrence].[OccurrenceDate] Between Date() And DateAdd('d',[tblOccurrence].[CoachingDate],Date()))));`

**EDIT #4:**
This query is the "best" beginning query I have gotten to work.  It pulls over ALL employee data then populates MaxCoaching and MaxDate.  So I tried connecting this query to your second query to get totals onto a query and can't get it working.

Query:
`SELECT tblEmployeeData.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.FName, Max(tblOccurrence.CoachingDate) AS LastCoachingDate, Max([OccurrenceDate]) AS MaxDate, tblEmployeeData.SupLName
FROM tblEmployeeData LEFT JOIN tblOccurrence ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = tblOccurrence.TechID
GROUP BY tblEmployeeData.SupLName, tblEmployeeData.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.FName`

So these results get the most recent Coaching Date (if any) and the most recent event date so I need to sum Occurrences based on 2 conditions:

1. If there is a coaching/other date within the last 6 months, it needs that occurrence total from that line PLUS any other dates that have occurred after their coaching/other date
2. If no coaching/other date has occurred within the last 6 months, then I need the total of occurrences within the last 6 months.

Moving closer to getting a working query!  Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "rolling previous 6 months" and is that different from "previous 6 months" and/or "previous 6 months"?  I guess I don't understand why you can't sum everything by Tech regardless of `OccurenceName`.

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well as your sample data? Thanks.

Comment: Edited for more clarity.  Hopefully that helps

Comment: @Zamael, I got how you calculate 9991 and 9998. However, for 9999, should it be 7.0 + 6.0 + 0.0 = 13? not 9

Comment: No... when a Tech has either a Coaching or "Other" within the previous 6 months, those entries supersede all occurrences prior.

Answer (score 0):

@Zamael if I understand your question and the clarifications, the reason 9998 sums to 9, is that the September dates are more than 6 months ago, and that there is another line item with an OccurenceAmt of 2 that we don't see in the table.

Assuming that's correct, I suggest that you create a query with the following SQL:

```
Select TechID, 
       SUM(IIF([OccurenceName] in ('Coaching','Other'),1,0)) as CoachingOtherCount,     
       SUM(IIF([OccurenceName] in ('Coaching','Other'),OccurenceAmt,0)) as CoachingAmt, 
       SUM(IIF(IIF([OccurenceName] in ('Coaching','Other'),0,OccurenceAmt))) as MiscAmt
From TableName
Where OccurenceDate > = DateAdd("m",-6,Date())
Group By TechID;
```

Then, Create a second query with following SQL:

```
select TechID,
       IIF(Nz(CoachingOtherCount,0) > 0, CoachingAmt, MiscAmt) as SumOccurenceAmt
from Query1;
```

**EDIT 1 - After Clarification**
What I understand now is:
Step 1: Find "Coaching" or "Other" in past 6 Months. If exists goto 2, else goto 3.
Step 2: Sum All lines occurring on or after the earliest from Step 1.
Step 3: Sum all lines from past 6 months.

If this is what you're looking for then the following code will work.

```
SELECT TechID, 
       MIN(IIF([OccurrenceName] in ('Coaching','Other'),OccurrenceDate,NULL)) AS MinCoachingOtherDate, 
       MIN([OccurrenceDate]) AS MinDate
FROM tblOccurrence
WHERE OccurrenceDate >= DateAdd("m",-6,Date())
GROUP BY TechID;
```

Then, in the second query

```
Select tbo.TechID,
       SUM([OccurrenceAmt]) as Amount

From tblOccurrence tbo
     LEFT JOIN QUERY1 q on q.techid = tbo.techid

WHERE tbo.OccurrenceDate >= IIF(q.MinCoachingOtherDate IS NULL, q.MinDate, q.MinCoachingOtherDate)

GROUP BY tbo.TechID;
```

The first query finds the earliest date for Coaching/Other in the first column if it exists, and simply the earliest date in the second. Then, in the second query we assume the Coaching/Other date unless it is null, then we default to the second date. Because the where constrains the dates dynamically for each TechID, you can just sum all of the OccurenceAmt.

Comment: I edited the data to show a better representation of what needs to be counted.  Your query returns the correct results but it's not clear to me that it is reliable if my data changes.  This DB will start to have a lot of data in it (over 120 "techs") so this will start to become quite complex.  I'm trying to throw all sorts of scenarios at it so it works in the long run.

Comment: @Zamael Thanks for the update to your post. If you can clarify for me why you indented lines 237 and 239 but not 247, I think can modify my answer to give you what you need.

Comment: The lines that should be showing indented are: 247, 237,238,239, 249,251 ... those are the lines that should be calculated

Comment: Updated the original post to provide even more additional details... getting closer!

Comment: @Zamael, the queries under edit 1 do exactly what you are mentioning in your logic. Please note the differences between your current query and the solution proposed. I made a mock database to replicate your data, and my queries worked like a charm.